# $resource callback with saved value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback

I've just started using AngularJS and I love it.

However - I have a need to save an item to my database using $resource and then get back and object containing the values of the newly created item in the database (especially the database-assigned ID).

I've found a few articles describing this - but none of them seems to work for me :(

I have a very simple setup:

```
var app = angular.module("todoApp", ['ngResource', 'ngAnimate']);
app.factory("TodoFactory", function ($resource) {
    return $resource('.../api/todo/:id', { id: '@id' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' }});
});

var todoController = app.controller("TodoController", function ($scope, TodoFactory) {

$scope.todos = [];

init();

function init() {
    $scope.todos = TodoFactory.query();
}

$scope.addTodo = function () {
    TodoFactory.save($scope.item, function () {
        // Success
        console.log($scope.item); // <--- HERE'S MY PROBLEM
        $scope.todos.push($scope.item);
        $scope.item = {};
    },
    function () {
        // Error 
    });
};
```

But when I call TodoFactory.save, the $scope.item does not contain the Id-property from the database - only the values it had upon calling save.

How can I get my setup to return the updated object with all the database-generated values?

If somebody could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated :)

**Update:** I just went over the source for the API I've been supplied - the save-method doesn't update the object that's inserted. 
After I fixed this "minor" issue, peaceman's example worked like a charm.

Sorry for the inconvenience everybody - but thank you very much for the responses! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `save` method of the `TodoFactory` won't update the `$scope.item`, but instead calls the callback function with the saved object as a parameter, that contains the new id.

So you have to replace

```
$scope.addTodo = function () {
    TodoFactory.save($scope.item, function () {
        // Success
        console.log($scope.item); // <--- HERE'S MY PROBLEM
        $scope.todos.push($scope.item);
        $scope.item = {};
    },
    function () {
        // Error 
    });
};
```

with

```
$scope.addTodo = function () {
    TodoFactory.save($scope.item, function (savedTodo) {
        // Success
        console.log(savedTodo);
        $scope.todos.push(savedTodo);
        $scope.item = {};
    },
    function () {
        // Error 
    });
};
```

This behaviour is documented at [ngResource.$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource)

Comment: I've been all over the ngResource.$resource documentation - but I can't get it working. 
I think I'm just missing some tiny bit in my code - but for the life of me I can't figure out where :) 

I'm able to get my object returned - but it's just the same object I passed in - it doesn't contain the database-generated values :(

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the problem.

```
$scope.addTodo = function () {

// ADD IN A VARIABLE FOR THE RESPONSE DATA AS THE PARAMETER TO YOUR SUCCESS CALLBACK FN
TodoFactory.save($scope.item, function (responseItem) {  
    // Success
    console.dir(responseItem);   // <--- AND THEN USE IT
    $scope.todos.push(responseItem);
    $scope.item = {};
},
function () {
    // Error 
});
};
```